# How to mark a failing test as an expected failure?

Tags: testing, cypress

Is there any way to mark a failing test as an expected failure? I have a test that is constantly failing, but it's a known bug and the ticket for this issue has been reported a while ago.

Comment: Please add the code of the test that is failing

Comment: https://docs.cypress.io/guides/core-concepts/writing-and-organizing-tests#Pending

Answer (score 4):

I would just use xit instead of it to skip the test. Above it I would add a comment with a link to the bug ticket. When it is done with xit, the test is shown as pending.

Answer (score 3):

In this scenario, it is better to skip the test which are failing if you don't want to delete the test and want to keep it once you know the reason of the test failure. Same is also mentioned in the [official documentation of jest](https://jestjs.io/docs/api#testskipname-fn).

So,  basically,  there are two ways to skip any test or test suite.

1. prefixing the `test` or `it` or `describe` with `x`

```cs
xdescribe(("test suite will be skipped") => {
  xtest(("this test is also skipped but don't use it with xdescribe") => {
    expect(true).toBe(true);
  })
 xit(("skip it test") => {
    expect(true).toBe(true);
  })
})
```

2. `skip()` api of `test`, `it` or `describe`

```cs
describe.skip(("test suite will be skipped") => {
  test.skip(("this test is also skipped but don't use it with describe.skip") => {
    expect(true).toBe(true);
  })
 it.skip(("skip it test") => {
    expect(true).toBe(true);
  })
})
```

Comment: I'd also recommend adding a comment above your skipped test with a link to your bug ticket for reference.